# Confusion in item selection (combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Number of ways to select 3 numbers from first 20 natural numbers (1 to 20) such that their product is even.
We know that there are 10 even and 10 odd numbers. To get even product, the selection can be as follows:

Method 1:

1. one even, two odd => ${10\choose 1}\times {10\choose2}$
2. two even, one odd => ${10\choose2}\times {10\choose 1}$
3. three even => $10 \choose 3$

Total number of ways will be ${10\choose 1}\times {10\choose2} + {10\choose2}\times {10\choose 1} + {10 \choose 3} = 1020$

Method 2: Select one even number and then select 2 more numbers form the remaining numbers => ${10\choose 1} \times {19 \choose 2} = 1710$

What is wrong with the Method 2?

Similarly, given 10 distinct items, we can pick three items in $10 \choose 3$ ways.

But if I consider it as a 3-step process of picking one item in each step, I get $10 \choose 1$ $9\choose 1$$8\choose1$, but since the selection is ordered^^, I divide by $3!$ to get $10\choose 1$$9\choose 1$$8\choose 1$$\frac1{3!}$ = $10 \choose 3$.
And if I consider it as a 2-step process of picking one item in the first step and 2 items in the second step, I get $10\choose1$$9\choose2$, and again I divide by $3!$ since the selection is ordered but before that I multiply with $2!$ because $9\choose 2$ part was unordered. Or simply $\frac{10!}{(10-1)!}
\frac{9!}{(9-2)!}\frac{1}{3!} = {10\choose3}$.

Using the similar logic in the above question of selecting three numbers, in 'Method 2', we can get $\frac{{10 \choose 1}{19 \choose 2}{2!}}{3!}$ which is still incorrect. Why is that so and what is actually happening with $10\choose 1$$19\choose 2$. How do I interpret it?

^^:I assume due to the way the selection is made, here, the 3-step process of selecting from the same set of items. But I'd like if someone throws more light on this. Because the 3-step process wouldn't have caused ordering if the selection was made from 3 disjoint set of items say blue, red and green items. Maybe because the selection set changes for successive selections in the former case but not in latter case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Think about choosing 10,12,13 and 12,10,13, and how that is treated in Method 2.

Comment: @AaaLol_dude ok so I get 1 way of selecting 10,12,13 and 1 way of selecting 12,10,13 with method 2, making a total of 2 ways of selecting this triplet, which is incorrect. There should have been only 1 way to select any particular triplet. On further inspection I notice that with method 2 I get twice the number of ways when two even and one odd number gets selected and thrice as much when three even numbers are selected. To remedy it, I can modify method 2 as 10C1.[9C2.2!/3! + 9C1.10C2/2! + 10C2] which reduces to method 1. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of ways of selecting $e$ of the ten even numbers and $3 - e$ of the ten odd numbers is $$\binom{10}{e}\binom{10}{3 - e},$$ the number of ways of selecting at least one even number when three numbers are selected from the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 20\}$ is indeed
$$\binom{10}{1}\binom{10}{2} + \binom{10}{2}\binom{10}{1} + \binom{10}{3}\binom{10}{0}$$
Therefore, your first method is correct, although it is not as efficient as the complementary counting method used by David G. Stork in his answer.

Your second method did not work since the set of even numbers is not disjoint from the set of additional numbers.  Therefore, you count each selection with two even numbers and each selection with three even numbers thrice, once for each way you could have designated one of the even numbers in your selection as the even number you have selected.

To illustrate, suppose you have selected the numbers $\{1, 2, 4\}$.  Your second method counts this selection twice:

$$\begin{array}{c c}
\text{even number} & \text{additional numbers}\\ 
\hline
2 & 1, 4\\
4 & 1, 2
\end{array}$$

If you had selected the numbers $\{2, 4, 6\}$, your second method counts this selection thrice.

$$\begin{array}{c c}
\text{even numbers} & \text{additional numbers}\\
\hline
2 & 4, 6\\
4 & 2, 6\\
6 & 2, 4
\end{array}$$

Notice that
$$\binom{10}{1}\binom{10}{2} + \color{red}{\binom{2}{1}}\binom{10}{2}\binom{10}{1} + \color{red}{\binom{3}{1}}\binom{10}{3}\binom{10}{0} = \color{red}{\binom{10}{1}\binom{19}{2}}$$

The expression $$\binom{10}{1}\binom{19}{2}$$ is the number of ways of painting one of the ten even numbers in the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 20\}$ blue and two of the remaining $19$ numbers in the set red.  Notice that painting one of the even numbers blue distinguishes it from any other number you select from the set.  However, there is no such distinction in the problem you posed.

Answer (score 1):

Method 2 is incorrect as you can get the same selection two ways (as illustrated by Aaa Lol_dude).

I prefer method 3:  Total number minus number of ways selecting *only* odds:

${20 \choose 3} - {10 \choose 3} = 1020$

Comment: Thanks but my aim with this question is not to find the correct solution. Instead it is to explore the incorrect approach, figure out the mistake and how to remedy it.